# What missions do not give unique loot?

Tags: borderlands-2

I'm trying to save all the missions with unique loot for a playthrough 2.5, so that I can get high level uniques.  My character is getting pretty severely underleveled in the process and is now too weak to take on higher level enemies.  Is there a list of the missions that one can do before playthrough 2.5 that do not give you any unique loot, so I can bring my level up a bit?

Comment: Can't you just start them all and look at the reward to make sure you don't do ones with loot as a reward?

Comment: The problem is that some of them give you loot in the form of people you kill during the mission who don't respawn.  Or maybe everyone respawns and I am just missing that?

Comment: Everyone respawns, the risks are only mission rewards given at the time of mission completion

Comment: While I can't really give an exact list, you should be eyeballing sidequests that give money, Eridium, or customization items to supplement your XP gain to ease the pain. Quests that grant green weapons/shields can also be used, as most of these are not unique.

Comment: You can't really 'underlevel' as such, there's always some quests that will be "Normal" or "Trival" rather than "Tough" or "Impossible". You can also go back to playthrough 1 to build up XP, but the enemies (and loot) is limited to level 30, so that doesn't work once you're over that.

Comment: And side-quest loot appears to be levelled to the quest, not to the level you are when you complete it, so any unique loot for completion is going to be underlevelled if you leave it and go back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ben Brocka is correct that bosses will respawn, so all that matters is quest rewards that are unique.  I've found a list someone else compiled of all missions that give unique loot ([source](http://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/showpost.php?p=2897666&postcount=191)).

- **A Real Boy: Human** -- Lying Pistol
- **Animal rights** -- Sniper "I infrequently perish"
- **Arms Dealing** -- One reward is a blue relic. Not unique. Maybe useful.
- **Bandit Slaughter Round 5** -- AR "What plaything can you offer me today?"
- **Bearer of Bad News** -- AR
- **Best Mother's Day Ever** -- Purple Shield. Roid. VERY LONG delay
- **BFFs** -- Order (Unique Shield)
- **Chosen One** -- Evil Smasher Assault Rifle.
- **Clan War: End of the Rainbow** -- Shotgun "Good things kill in threes"
- **Clan War: Wakey Wakey** -- Unique Pistol or Shield.
- **Clan War: Zafords v Hodunks** -- SMG or Shotgun.
- **Cordially Invited/Tea Party** -- Corrosive Teapot
- **Cult Following: The Enkindling** -- Shield of the Firehawk
- **Demon Hunter** -- Red Text Ironsight Sniper.
- **Doctor's Orders** -- Blue Relic?
- **Hell Hath No Fury** -- Grenade "It takes two to get one in trouble"
- **Home Movies** -- 2 blue relics to choose from
- **Hungry Like the Skag** -- AR "Oh sorry. Was that your head?"
- **Hyperion Contract 873** -- Talking Sniper
- **Hyperion Slaughter 5** -- Sniper
- **Lost Treasure** -- Lists as Green Pistol. Possibly Red Text?
- **Medical Mystery: XCOM-Municate** -- Possible E-Tech Gun?
- **Note for Self Person** -- Launcher "Toasty"
- **Out of Body Experience** -- Talking Shotgun
- **Overlooked: Only a Test** - Purple Shield. "What do you mean Theoretically"
- **Positive Self Image** -- Vehicle Booster Relic. No Red Text. Still maybe rare.
- **Pretty Good Train Robbery** -- Grenade. "Make it Rain"
- **Rakkaholic's Anonymous** -- Sniper or Pistol
- **Safe and Sound** -- Shotgun or Unique Relic.
- **Showdown** -- Red Text Relic. +Shotgun Damage, Reload and FFYL. Uncertain if it  - **scales.
- **Slap Happy** -- Shotgun. "Octo means 9"
- **Splinter Group** -- Shotgun. "Don't Retreat, instead reload!"
- **The Bane** -- The Bane
- **The Good, The Bad and the Mordecai** -- Relic with +XP from combat.
- **Uncle Teddy** -- Pistol or Shotgun
- **Won't Get Fooled Again** -- Law?
- **You. Will. Die. (Seriously.)** -- Inconclusive. Possibly irrelevant.

Answer (score -2):

Well buddy i don't think you need to save the mission for later. As Feeble said Rewards doesn't level up with you(in same play-through). Let me explain a bit.

you need to finish the game i.e. you need to kill the warrior to open True vault hunter mode, once its open you need to select is from character selection menu. you will get all the side-quest again in second/third play-through (Doesn't matter if you have completed those quest in last playthorugh). I completed all the quests both the times, now looking forward to playthrough 2.5, I have 2 unique (Flame of firehawk lvl 11 and lvl 40. I did Clayton's quest both times, so think you can do it over and no need to worry about missing those unique.) from 1st and True vault hunter mode.

By the way this information is regarding PC version of borderlands, don't if its different in XBOX version.

Comment: This is incorrect. All sidequests that are not accepted are scaled up to level 50 - both in enemies that you must deal with and their quest rewards - upon killing the final boss in True Vault Hunter Mode. Thus, for people who wish to use unique quest rewards like the talking sniper rifle, talking shotgun, etc. at level 50, skipping these sidequests until that point is a method of getting these rewards at level 50.

Comment: wasnt aware of that let me try it out today and will let you know.

Comment: Dont know how you could be in play-through 2.5 and not 50 level i am on True Vault hunter mode most side-quest skipped, half way(angel mission completed) and I am already lvl 50.

Answer (score -3):

First and foremost there's no point in waiting until playthrough 2.5 to get unique weapons.  The mission rewards don't scale with your level, they stay the same through each playthrough and they'll increase for the next playthrough, when you can do the mission again. There's no reason whatsoever not to do the quests now and reap the benefits. You'll be getting the same things only better on subsequent playthroughs anyway.

Oh, and yeah, every boss you face and almost all minibosses respawn as well. You just have to save and quit, then reload and they'll be there. You can farm them this way in order to get their rare drops.

Comment: False; some of these rewards (mostly non-unique ones) do not scale with level, but many unique weapons will scale up to or near your level. Since there are only two playthroughs you'll permanently lose the ability to get certain mission-only items at level 50 this way

Comment: I have never seen a unique quest reward scale to my level. In fact it was one of my criticisms of the game that I'd get some great reward with a unique effect...that was 4 levels beneath me.

Comment: They only scale once you hit playthrough 2.5, and only some of them. Not sure which, but the LadyFist and Order shield were scaled up, most non-uniques weren't, and a few uniques weren't.