# What happens to DLC missions in the second playtrough

Tags: borderlands-2

I just recently started Borderlands 2, and I haven't played the first one, so I am a bit confused by the second playthrough. I have searched and read about it, but I am not quite sure I fully understand it. Maybe you guys can help out. I want to get 'the most' out of the game, so good loot / xp levels.

From what I understand I can play the game in 3 stages:

1) First, I do all the story missions and side missions. I can also do all the DLCs, since I have the season pass. All missions, including DLC missions will reset in the next playthrough.

2) When I have done all of that I can now activate the second playthrough called TVHM. In this mode all the missions will reset. So the main mission resets, the side missions, AND the DLC? In this mode I must only do the main storyline again, and leave all the other missions open.

3) When I beat the storyline the second time I can now do all the side missions again, and do all the DLC's again. Now every mission I do will scale to my level. This is also the mode where the loot is the best because I will prob be lvl 50 already. It will also be really hard.

---

Am I correct here, or did I miss anything? I am not sure if the DLCs reset also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The DLCs do reset so you can do it again.  However, its beneficial on the second playthrough to complete ONLY the main storyline missions first, this brings you to a new mode called playthrough 2.5.  In playthrough 2.5, all mission and rewards will be set to the max level of 50, so you'll gain much better unique weapons than if you completed them at lower levels.

You must not even accept a side mission until you reach playthrough 2.5 as the mission level is locked in as soon as you accept it.

Comment: I failed miserably at not accepting ALL the quests

Comment: It's totally okay to accept quests without blue rewards for the most part, actually

Comment: I wish I knew that the FIRST time I went through the game

Answer (score 1):

Missions do not *reset* in playthrough 2.5, only stuff left from playthrough 2 remains. That's why it not "3" but "2.5". DLC's also do not reset - if you go to DLC's right at the start of playthrough 2, those areas and quests will be of the level you first entered.

A couple more corrections:

- In playthrough 2, you are free to accept any side quests that do not have Unique rewards, as it helps to level up. Rule of thumb is - Uniques are blue, though not every blue is a Unique. After a couple playthroughs you will memorize them, for now [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/87356/33619) and [there](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1J-_mBuRyMTFAUiRXcLSdtaMqPl0vzC-r_FSkBwuyKtU/edit) are lists.
- Loot will be the best once you reach enemies and quests of level 50, not playthrough 2.5 itself. Therefore, in playthrough 2 you are free to accept any side missions that are level 50, no need to go finish the game first - a level 50 Fibber will still be a level 50 Fibber.
- DLCs do scale to your level, so, similarly, you are free to divert to DLC as soon as (or shortly before) you ding 50, so you can reap all those pirate chests and Torgue fwap-a-booms at level 50 and go end the game with them.

A good example of OP stuff you can grab at level 50 while still on playthrough 2 is The Bee, the Fibber and the Sand Hawk.

Comment: The teapot is also an awesome level 50 weapon.

Comment: @spartacus But it is **not** an example of an awesome level 50 weapon you can grab on **playthrough 2**. Quest level is around 40 on PT2 - this one has to be postponed to PT2.5.

Comment: true (12 chars)